# How to group pandas dataframe by unequal time interval or string value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 5 minute time granularity. By now I group the df by cutting it down to the entire day and read the min / max values from two columns:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1D')).agg({'Low':[np.min],'High':[np.max] })
```

Now, instead of getting the whole day, I need to boil the dataframe down to a split day, with unequal intervals. Let's say 7:00 to 15:00 and 15:00 to 22:00.
How could I do it? `freq=''` allows only equal intervals.
I also have a column with value 'A' for the first part of the day, and 'B' for the second part of the day, in case it's easier to group.

```
Date                    High    Low     Session
0   2019-06-20 07:00:00 2927.50 2926.75 A
1   2019-06-20 07:05:00 2927.50 2927.00 A
2   2019-06-20 07:10:00 2927.25 2926.50 A
3   2019-06-20 07:15:00 2926.75 2926.25 A
4   2019-06-20 07:20:00 2926.75 2926.00 A
```

Comment: Do you just throw out anything between (22:00:00, 7:00:00)?

Comment: @ALollz yes, my df ends actually at 22:15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your Session column

```
df = df.groupby([df.Date.dt.date, 'Session']).agg({'Low':'min', 'High':'max'})
```

Or you can make your own with `pd.cut`

```
df = (
    df.groupby([df.Date.dt.date,
        pd.cut(df.Date.dt.hour, bins=[7, 15, 22], labels=['7-15', '15-22'])])
    .agg({'Low':'min', 'High':'max'})
)
```